# Python Cumsum. Any easy way to handle with Pandas GroupBY or Transform?

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I am trying to find out the best way or easiest way to find the cumsum of the quantities after sorting by date and itemID.

Current structure is:

```
Date,   CompanyID,  LocationID, ItemID, Quantity
8/31/2020,  113,    DALLAS, Item1,  1
8/31/2020,  113,    DALLAS, Item2,  1
9/1/2020,   113,    DALLAS, Item2,  359
9/1/2020,   113,    MICHIGAN,   Item3,  20
9/3/2020,   113,    DALLAS, Item1,  1
9/3/2020,   113,    DALLAS, Item1,  57
9/3/2020,   113,    DALLAS, Item2,  31
10/29/2020, 113,    DALLAS, Item3,  15
10/29/2020, 113,    DALLAS, Item1,  20
```

And expected result set is:

```
Date,   CompanyID,  LocationID, ItemID, Quantity,   CUMSUV
8/31/2020,  113,    DALLAS, Item1,  1,  1
9/3/2020,   113,    DALLAS, Item1,  1,  2
9/3/2020,   113,    DALLAS, Item1,  57, 59
10/29/2020, 113,    DALLAS, Item1,  20, 99
8/31/2020,  113,    DALLAS, Item2,  1,  1
9/1/2020,   113,    DALLAS, Item2,  359,    360
9/3/2020,   113,    DALLAS, Item2,  31, 391
10/29/2020, 113,    DALLAS, Item3,  15, 15
9/1/2020,   113,    MICHIGAN    Item3,  20, 20
```

Tried things like:

```
results= results.groupby(['LocationID', 'ItemID', 'Date']).sum(['Quantity'])
or 
results["CUMSUV"] = results.groupby(['ItemID'])['Quantity'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)
```

Comment: `results["CUMSUV"] = results.groupby('ItemID')['Quantity'].cumsum()` ?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
def.sort_values(by=['ItemID', 'Date']).groupby('ItemID')['Quantity'].cumsum()
```